# emulating touch events for Chrome - is there a better way?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, gwt, mobile

I'm using Chrome with source maps for debugging a GWT-based app.  It's very nice.  What I want to do now is have Chrome pretend to be a mobile device.  I turned on "emulate touch events", but it seems that the mouse events are still being generated as well.  What I was hoping for would be that the browser would act more or less exactly like a mobile browser.  I can run my code in XCode's iOS simulator, but can't debug it easily.  Thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that a real touch device doesn't *also* send mouse events when a touch occurs?

If you test this, I'm certain you'll find that a real touch device actually generates some mouse events when a tap or touch start/move/end occurs. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Touch_events to see how to avoid generating mouse events, at least on real touch devices... it may not work in chrome, but you have to at least start there.

Comment: Not sure  Is there a web page that I can visit on a touch device (we're talking iPad here) that will show me touch and mouse events?

Comment: Do you mean besides the samples on that page I linked? Or setting up the various touch events with GWT and compiling it to run on the device?

Comment: Colin, not really.  What I was looking for is a way to get the browser to behave more identically to a touch device, rather than having to use Apple's iOS emulator, in which it's a royal pain to debug.  Thanks.

Comment: ... like maybe a different browser that's built for this purpose, or a Chrome plugin maybe.

Comment: Right, and I'm trying to tell you that touch devices send mouse events. That is what the MDN page says, and what you would find if you tested a real touch device. They do this so that apps designed for a mouse still work with touch. This is deliberate, so Chrome might well be actually emulating the device, and you are asking it *not* to.